# Slick Slider - Multiple Sliders with variations in Slider Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Hello my dear community,

I'm working on a site with multiple sliders on one site. I use slick.js

Problem ist that the slidesToShow is depending on the number of slider items.

- Maximum slidesToShow should be 6
- if the number of slides is smaller then 6:
  -> slidesToShow should be the number of slider items

I tried this:

```
 $('.carousel').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: $(this).querySelectorAll( '.item:not(.slick-cloned)' ).length > 4 ? 6 : 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
```

Got console error that querySelectorAll is not a function. Also $(this) is the document not the slider in that context.

Also I tried to iterate through the sliders and tried to initializing them one by one but it also does not work

```
var imgcarousels = document.getElementsByClassName('vaunet-carousel ');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(imgcarousels, function(carousel, index) {
    console.log(carousel);

carousel.slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 991,
                settings: {
                    dots: true,
                    arrows: false,
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Error: carousel.slick is not a function

Any Idea how to make the slidesToShow depending on the slides?

Thanks a ton <3

Regards
Timo

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is a `Document`'s method (see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)) while `$(this)` is some element in the document.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you provide a [mcve]

Comment: The issue seem that the "this" does not refer to the slider element within the options object. One way to achieve what you want is to iterate over each .carousel element and determine the number of items, then initialize Slick with the appropriate slidesToShow value.

Comment: @user580950 thanks for you answer. I tried to iterate through the elements in the second code example. But it seems that slick slider needs a class selector for the init function. Am I wrong?